How to filter polars dataframe by first maximum value while using over?
I am trying to filter a dataframe to find the first occurrence of a maximum value over a category column. In my data there is no guarantee that there is a single unique maximum value, there could be multiple values, but i only need the first occurance.
Yet I can't seem to find a way to limit the max part of the filter, currently I am then adding a further filter on another column generally a time based one and taking the minimum value.
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "cat": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        "max_col": [12, 24, 36, 15, 50, 50, 45, 20, 40, 60],
        "other_col": [25, 50, 75, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275],
    }
)

df = df.filter(pl.col("max_col") == pl.col("max_col").max().over("cat")).filter(
    pl.col("other_col") == pl.col("other_col").min().over("cat")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ cat ┆ max_col ┆ other_col │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64     ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 36      ┆ 75        │
│ 2   ┆ 50      ┆ 150       │
│ 3   ┆ 60      ┆ 275       │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────┘

However, I'd prefer to simplify the above to only require passing in references to the max and category columns.
Am I missing something obvious here?
EDIT: Added example dataframe and output.

Does this mean other_col is guaranteed to be sorted? (and is only used to provide the "first" behaviour in this case?)

The real data values are recorded during material performance testing so the it’s not guaranteed to be in order but I need the max value per category to then determine other parameters at the max value. Hopefully that makes sense. And thank you for your post I’m away from my computer to test but will do so for yours and Roman Pekars answers.

You can add .is_first_distinct() to the filter to keep only the first max.
df.filter(
    pl.all_horizontal(
        pl.col("max_col") == pl.col("max_col").max(),
        pl.col("max_col").is_first_distinct()
    )
    .over("cat")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ cat ┆ max_col ┆ other_col │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64     ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 36      ┆ 75        │
│ 2   ┆ 50      ┆ 150       │
│ 3   ┆ 60      ┆ 275       │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────┘


It's not clear from the arg_max docs which index it returns though when there are multiple. Might be the first, but might be any other, including the last or an arbitrary.

@levantpied I think the docs just need clarification. I believe it is guaranteed to be the first - similar to how it works in pandas: "If the maximum is achieved in multiple locations, the first row position is returned."

@levantpied You were right about arg_min/max - there will be no such guarantee in Polars: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/18390

I'd suggest the following approach:

DataFrame.group_by() by cat column first
Expr.sort_by() within the group by max_col
take the Expr.first() row.

There're could be 2 options:
If you want first occurence of max(max_col)
In this case you want to use maintain_order = True during sorting:
(
    df
    .group_by('cat', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.all()
        .sort_by('max_col', descending=True, maintain_order=True).first()
    )
)

or, using DataFrame.sort() and group_by.first():
(
    df
    .sort('max_col', descending=True, maintain_order=True)
    .group_by('cat', maintain_order=True)
    .first()
)

┌─────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ cat ┆ max_col ┆ other_col │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64     ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 36      ┆ 75        │
│ 2   ┆ 50      ┆ 150       │
│ 3   ┆ 60      ┆ 275       │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────┘

If you need to rely on the order of other_col
In this case you can additionally sort by other_col:
(
    df
    .group_by('cat', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.all()
        .sort_by('max_col','other_col', descending=[True, False]).first()
    )
)

# or

(
    df
    .sort('max_col','other_col', descending=[True, False])
    .group_by('cat', maintain_order=True)
    .first()
)

┌─────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ cat ┆ max_col ┆ other_col │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64     ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 3   ┆ 60      ┆ 275       │
│ 2   ┆ 50      ┆ 150       │
│ 1   ┆ 36      ┆ 75        │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────┘


This worked ok, but both methods didn't always select the first occurrence of the max value. But without an example was really impressed it got me so close to the solution.

Yes if “first one” is the one you need then @jcurious solution is spot on. If you need to choose the one based on other columns then the solution should work

It might be a requirement in future tools so definitely of use

I've also updated the solution for the 'first' occurence of the max value
